# Spring Boot2.0 - @SessonScope cannot be updated and is not reflected in HttpSession

Tags: spring-boot, session-scope, spring-boot-2, spring-boot-migration-1.5.x-2.1.x

In Spring Boot1.5, it was possible to update the instance with @SessionScope.
However, when Spring Boot 2.0 is used, the value is not updated and it remains null.

**Session-scoped component:**

```
@Data
@SessionScope
public class UserDto {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  @Autowired
  UserDto userInfo;

  @RequestMapping("/greeting")

  public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", name);
      userInfo.setFirstName("John");
      userInfo.setLastName("Smith");
      /**
      * There was null value in Spring Boot 2.0. 
      * In Spring Boot 1.5 it was "John".
      **/
      System.out.println(userInfo.getFirstName()); 
      return "greeting";
  }
}
```

[debug result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ09b.png)

Comment: HTML(Thymeleaf): [[${session.userInfo.firstName}]] is null. In Spring Boot 1.5 it was "John".

Comment: welcome to stackoveflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour